# Указатели на функцию. Вызов указателя функции из базового класса в классе наследнике.

Tags: c++

Очередной мой тупик в изучении языка. Прошу помочь со сложившейся  ситуацией. В общем задача такая. Есть базовый класс:

```
class TABase {

public:
    typedef void (TABase::*Action)(void*);
    std::tr1::unordered_map<const char*, Action> baseMap;

public: 
    Action getAction(const char* name);
};
```

В котором описан указатель на функцию, мапа, в которой будут храниться const char* в качестве ключа и адрес функции, так же метод в котором будет возвращаться адрес полученный поиском из мапы по ключу.

Затем создаем класс наследник:

```
class TAChild : public TABase  {

public:
    void addInMap();
    void testMethod(void* sender);
};
```

В котором в методе addInMap мы должны будем заполнить мапу. Пытаюсь сделать я это так:

```
TABase::Action act = &this->testMethod;
std::pair<const char*, TABase::Action> mapPair("name", act);
baseMap.insert(mapPair);
```

Вот тут и возникают у меня проблемы. Возникает ошибка: **error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression**

Помогите разобраться, в том каким образом я могу указателю на функцию  из базового класса присвоить адрес функции наследника, для того чтобы поместить в мапу именно в классе наследника?

Answer (score 1):

```
TABase::Action act = &(TAChild::testMethod);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
TABase::Action act = &this->testMethod;//1.сначала взять адрес переменной this
                                       //2.затем вызвать у этого адреса метод testMethod
```

---

```
TABase::Action act = &(this->testMethod);//1.сначала получить адрес метода
                                         //2.затем взять адрес адреса из "1"
```